# convert datetime.date(hh) to int python django

Tags: python, python-datetime

how to convert DateTime.time to int?...

I have `datetime.time(23)` that 23 representatives as hours.

minutes and second will be ignore, just take the hours.

I need to convert it to int, so example:

`overtime_count = datetime.time(23) - datetime.time(14)`

`overtime_count = 9`

i want that `9` can multiple by int. example `9 * 20 = 180`

Comment: thank you @md-khairul-basar any solution maybe?

Comment: datetime.time(hh).hour will give you hh as int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do `.hour`:

```
print(datetime.time(23).hour)
# 23
```

To calculate overtime:

```
overtime_count = datetime.time(23).hour - datetime.time(14).hour
# 9
```